# How to generate an Eclipse formatter configuration from a checkstyle configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle configuration XML file and want to automatically generate an Eclipse formatter configuration from this. Is there any tool that can do this?

Comment: Dear Ken, some of us think you really should accept the above answer as the best (not sure that Paul is running after the Unsung hero's badge ;))

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy done, thanks for the ping!

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy It's good that the answer was accepted, but unsung hero would be for users that have accepted answers with 0 votes, rather than lots of votes without being accepted. (Just trying to save others from having to search what unsung hero badge means)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In Eclipse (3.6):

- Install [Checkstyle plug-in](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/)
- Import stylesheet using Windows --> Preferences, General --> Checkstyle --> New. Since you have an external file, choose "external file" as the type.

Right-click on your project in the Package view and select Checkstyle --> Create Formatter-Profile.

Then enable the formatter for your workspace: Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter. Select formatter: "eclipse-cs [project name]".

Click OK!

Comment: which file should I import into the Eclipse check-style plug-in for the Google Java style - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/? I tried `styleguide.css`, but that failed.

Comment: Looks like it depends on the programming language: [C++](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/eclipse-cpp-google-style.xml) [Java](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) You need an XML file in any case, not a CSS.

Comment: This feature is broken and the Eclipse plugin authors said in March 2019 that they were planning to remove it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55323793/733092

Comment: @Noumenon is there an alternative AFAYK?

Comment: @MarcoBolis I never found one and just ran it from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

The answer currently marked as accepted does not work as is with `Eclipse 2022-06` and `Checkstyle Plug-in 10.0.0`. These are the steps that worked for me:

1. Install [Checkstyle plug-in](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/)
2. Import Checkstyle configuration: `Windows -> Preferences -> Checkstyle -> New`. Choose "external file" as the type.
3. Right-click on your project in the `Package view` and select `Checkstyle -> Create Formatter-Profile`. The following files will be created in you project:

- `my-project-cs-cleanup.xml`
- `my-project-cs-formatter.xml`

4. Add the generated `my-project-cs-formatter.xml` as a formatter: `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Import`