# converting an eclipse formatter file to a checkstyle file

Tags: maven, maven-2, continuous-integration, maven-plugin, checkstyle

I have an eclipse formatting file (which contains some configurations) and i want to make the same thing (these configurations) for a checkstyle file to use after with maven build.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to convert a formatter file to a checkstyle ruleset at the moment. You have to do it the other way around as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984778/how-to-generate-an-eclipse-formatter-configuration-from-a-checkstyle-configurati).

Otherwise you have to adjust every setting in your formatter manually for checkstyle.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse-Checkstyle plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) provides an export feature to export your preferences.

Comment: This answer might answer the question but does not provide any info on how to do it.