# Create a Checkstyle Configuration from an Eclipse formatter file

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, formatter

At the moment our team is working with a custom eclipse Formatter configuration. Is there a way to import the generated xml file into Checkstyle to have both on the same ruleset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting an eclipse formatter file to a checkstyle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327498/converting-an-eclipse-formatter-file-to-a-checkstyle-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327498/converting-an-eclipse-formatter-file-to-a-checkstyle-file), there is no way to convert a formatter file to a checkstyle ruleset at the moment. The formater file has another syntax as checkstyle, so it's unable to read it.

Comment: thx for your answer. Very sad as it works the other way around. I will wirte my ruleset now in checkstyle and export it as eclipse formatter.

Answer (score 0):

> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style - > Formatter

You can import/export or create a new format rules.

Comment: That is not the problem, I have the eclipse formatter xml file exported but I can't import it to checkstyle. When I try checkstyle tells me that there is "no grammar found"

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the file? Try export from eclipse where this formatter is working one more time. If this does not help than open file in notepad++ and check syntaxt, may some tags are not properly closed or sth like this(formatter is xml file).