# How to convert eclipse formatter.xml into Checkstyle rules

Tags: eclipse, maven, formatting, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

*Similar question has been asked before, but it was years back. Think some solution might be there but unable to find it.*

**I have a custom eclipse formatter.xml. Need to convert it to Checkstyle rules.xml to enforce formatting in maven project using maven-checkstyle-plugin.**

Tried formatter-maven-plugin, but getting inconsistent results on different machines

Any other way to enforce custom formatting check in maven would also suffice. Use case - CI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Checkstyle Configuration from an Eclipse formatter file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499984/create-a-checkstyle-configuration-from-an-eclipse-formatter-file)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to read the ['How do I ask a good question'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327498/converting-an-eclipse-formatter-file-to-a-checkstyle-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644171/1549977), there is no way to convert a formatter file to a checkstyle ruleset at the moment. The formater file has another syntax as checkstyle, so it's unable to read it.

Comment: You found some weird answers to adapt their behaviour ^^. For example the first sentence borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62057554/1) doesn't belong into an answer post. The second thing is writing an answer to point to other answers, like the other user did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644171). Instead flag the question as a duplicate (you did that already, thank you).