# Eclipse formatter should use CheckStyle

Tags: java, eclipse, format, checkstyle

If I use a project related CheckStyle configuration in an XML file which uses:

```
<module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
</module>
```

I want the project specific formatter to automatically format the code that left braces have a newline before.
How can this be done automatically without configuring it twice?

Comment: I think your question has an answer here: [How to generate an Eclipse formatter configuration from a checkstyle configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/984778/1005481)

Comment: thx that's want I've searched for