# Problem with Checkstyle: Creating formatter profile

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I downloaded the checkstyle plugin for university in order to check the code like my professor wants it. We got an xml configuration file and i created with that another checkstyle configuration (Preferences -> Checkstyle -> New...) Also I set it as default. Now we have to create an automatic formatter like "Rightclick project -> Checkstyle -> Create Formatter-profile". Now I get an problem popup from eclipse with the message: 
"An internal error occurred during: "transformCheckstyle".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/preferences/PreferencesAccess

This is the full error message from the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-12-02 16:42:24.496
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "transformCheckstyle".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/preferences/PreferencesAccess
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.transformer.FormatterConfigWriter.writeCleanupSettings(FormatterConfigWriter.java:95)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.transformer.FormatterConfigWriter.writeSettings(FormatterConfigWriter.java:89)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.transformer.FormatterConfigWriter.<init>(FormatterConfigWriter.java:81)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.transformer.CheckstyleTransformer.transformRules(CheckstyleTransformer.java:124)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.jobs.TransformCheckstyleRulesJob.runInWorkspace(TransformCheckstyleRulesJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SESSION 2018-12-02 16:44:15.808 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Comment: Did you go through [the steps outlined here](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/#!/project-setup)?

Comment: Yeah the checkstyle works fine, when I use Checkstyle -> activate Checkstyle and I add my checkstyle config for global projects and not a specific but it is the same, when I try to create a formatter profile from my current checkstyle config

Comment: Issue already reported at https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/107 .

Comment: @rveach Your comment should be the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CheckStyle had this bug reported:
https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/107

It has been fixed so upgrade to the latest CheckStyle version for Eclipse.

Comment: Just for clarity, Eclipse-CS is the one talking about removing the feature, not the main Checkstyle team. The Checkstyle team doesn't have the expertise to maintain the eclipse plugin but we help out by hosting it under our umbrella on github.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has already been reported at https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/107 but no one has contributed a fix for it.