# VSCode format Java code based on checkstyle sun_checks.xml

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, checkstyle

I would like to format my Java files in VSCode using the Checkstyle Sun Checks format (https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml)

I understand that we can set the format in VSCode by setting the following parameter in `settings.json`

```
"java.format.settings.url": ""
```

However, the above parameter needs the file as `Eclipse formatter xml`.

Is `sun_checks` available in the above format?

Answer (score 0):

So for there is no way to convert a checkstyle rules file to the format setting file in VS Code.

But there is a workaround. You can first export that file in Eclipse, and then set it in VS Code. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665882/13068918.